# How to access a scroll view sub class from the main view controller (Beginner)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview

Using swift 3, I have a UIScrollView in my main view. I call it my "feature scroll view"

I have also added a custom class to my UIScrollView, which has one function in it called `loadFeatures()`

featureScrollView.swift:

```
class featureScrollView: UIScrollView {

public func loadFeatures () {
    //Add Pictures to the UIScrollView
}
```

How do i call `loadFeatures()` on the UIScrollView instance that exists from my ViewController.swift class in my main view?

In my ViewController.swift I want to simply write

```
scrollView.loadFeatures()
```

and have the code in `loadFeatures()` apply to the scrollView that is currently on the screen. I am beginning learning Swift and I appreciate everybody's help greatly!

[image of ScrollView and corresponding class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HRH0.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the IBOutlet of scrollview (Scrollview that you have shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HRH0.png) in your ViewController.swift and just call loadFeatures() from ViewController.swift with that outlet instace.

ex., once you bind outlet like as below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: featureScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.loadFeatures()
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already made a custom class for your ScrollView you could easily access that by subclassing your scrollView in your `*.storyboard`

For example:

You could set the custom class of your scrollView by placing it in here

[image]

Which would look like this

[image]

**Note:** This is just one way of doing things

Another is to do it manually inside your `UIViewController` class like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ftScrollView: FeatureScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ftScrollView = FeatureScrollView()  // I Initialized the scrollView
        ftScrollView.frame = // some frame here
        view.addSubView(ftScrollView)
        ftScrollView.loadFeatures()

    }
}
```

**PS:** Please conform to swift coding standards. You should always start class names with a capital letter, thus this `class featureScrollView: UIScrollView` should be named like this `class FeatureScrollView: UIScrollView`

Comment: @KevinT mark one of us as the correct answer to close the issue or answer your own question if you solved it another way.